# Printing pointer in a loop

Tags: pointers, printf

I am trying to print the numbers entered by the user, it can be any amount so I used pointers. I am having a tough time to print them out. 
Here is my code:

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int i,n;
    int *elements;
    printf("Enter the number of elements to be sorted\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    elements = malloc(sizeof(int)*n);
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", *elements);
    }
    printf("Elements before sorting\n");
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        printf("%d \n", *elements);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please tell us, what does not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First**

You have to pass to *scanf* an address to read to. Since you also are iterating, change

```
scanf("%d", *elements);
```

to

```
scanf("%d", &elements[i]);
```

**Second**

When printing remember that you are iterating the values. So change

```
printf("%d \n", *elements);
```

to

```
printf("%d \n", elements[i]);
```

---

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int i,n;
    int *elements;
    printf("Enter the number of elements to be sorted\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    elements = malloc(sizeof(int)*n);
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &elements[i]);
    }

        printf("Elements before sorting\n");
        for (i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            printf("%d \n", elements[i]);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Say `printf("%d \n", elements[i]);`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int i,n;
    int *elements;
    printf("Enter the number of elements to be sorted\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    elements = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*n); 
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", elements+i); 
    }

        printf("Elements before sorting\n");
        for (i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            printf("%d \n", *(elements+i)); 
        }
}
```

1. `malloc()` returns a `void*` pointer, you should exlicitly convert it to `int*`, so that the compiler could know the length of a step while traversing the block of memory.
2. `scanf()` needs an address as augment. That's why you use `&n` instead of `n`. But `elements` is a pointer, its value is already an address, so just use `elements` is ok, but not `*elements`.
3. you should increase the `elements` in both of the `for` loops, or all the numbers would be stored into the same address and replaced one by one.